# Angular | How to pass the id of a select between two functions?

Tags: angular

I have this select inside a form in the HTML from which I retrieve the ID of the selected value.

```
 <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>Select an user</mat-label>
          <mat-select disableRipple #selectVal id="valueSelect" formControlName="user" 
            (selectionChange)="idUser($event.value)">
            <mat-option #userPost id="userPostId" *ngFor="let user of users" 
           [value]="user.id">{{user.name}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

And with this method I recover the id of the select in my component.ts

```
idUser(value: any) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

Only that the id of the select I actually need within this other method which will then be used to add a new post. To be precise, I have to update the value of this.postService.userid of the following method:

```
addPost(title: string, body: string): void {
  title = title.trim();
  body = body.trim();
  this.postService.APIkey = this.urlToken as string
  
  this.postService.userid = // HERE I need the ID value of the select

    this.postService.addPosts(title, body).subscribe((data) => {
      window.location.reload()
    },
    (error)=>{
      if (error.status) {
        alert('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error.error));
      }
 });
    
}
```

Is there any way to do this? I can't find any viable alternative. Can anyone help me?

Comment: If `addPost` is on that same component, just pass it to it instead since `idUser` doesn't appear to actually be doing anything. If you need it in multiple places, make it a model. Add a `userId` property to the component class, then add to the `mat-select` `[(ngModel)]="userId"` (I'm assuming `mat-select` supports `ngModel`), then use `this.userId` wherever.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what kind of property should I put in userId? can you give me an example? I'm studying Angular now, it's all new to me.

Comment: I mean make `userId` a property of the component class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make `userId` a property of your component and then use that inside the `addPost` method:

```
@Component({...})
export class YourComponent {
    selectedUserId: string;

    idUser(value: any) {
        console.log(value);
        this.selectedUserId = value;
    }

    addPost(title: string, body: string): void {
        title = title.trim();
        body = body.trim();
        this.postService.APIkey = this.urlToken as string;
        this.postService.userid = this.selectedUserId;

        this.postService.addPosts(title, body).subscribe((data) => {
                window.location.reload()
            },
            (error) => {
                if (error.status) {
                    alert('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error.error));
                }
            });
    }
}
```

But if you have more than one form-field and also need form-field validation, I'd recommend using form-controls. There is a nice tutorial on the offical angular page: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms